# Symfony: qpush subcriber don't handle AWS SNS message

Tags: symfony, amazon-web-services, push-notification

I'm using the qpush-bundle to send push messages to my application. The goal is to perform asynchronous tasks.

I'm using AWS SQS and SNS to dispatch my message back to my symfony application, that then should be handled by the service I configured.

From the docs:

> Once a message is received via POST from your Message Queue, a `MessageEvent` is dispatched which can be handled by your services. Each `MessageEvent` contains the name of the queue and a `Uecode\Bundle\QPushBundle\Message\Message` object, accessible through getters.

### My problem:

**The event does not seems to be catched:** The processing in my service is not performed.

```
class AsyncService
{
    public function onMessageReceived(MessageEvent $event)
    {
        // do some processing
    }
}
```

---

### Additional info:

The notification is correctly sent, as I verified in the access_log:

```
"POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 45 "-" "Amazon Simple Notification Service Agent"
```

config.yml:

```
uecode_qpush:
providers:
    aws:
        driver: aws
        key: '%aws_access_key%'
        secret: '%aws_secret%'
        region: eu-central-1
queues:
    civbq:
        provider: aws
        options:
            queue_name: myqueuename
            push_notifications: true
            subscribers:
                - { endpoint: https://my-site.com/, protocol: https }
```

services.yml:

```
async_service:
    class: AppBundle\Service\AsyncService
    arguments: [@doctrine.orm.entity_manager, @uecode_qpush]
    tags:
        - { name: uecode_qpush.event_listener, event: myqueuename.message_received, method: onMessageReceived }
```

Also I had to create a SNS topic named "myqueuename", to not get a `Topic does not exist` error.

Answer (score 0):

It `event: civbq.message_received` rather than `event: myqueuename.message_received`, the [new documentation](http://qpush-bundle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html) make this clearer, civbq is the queue key, and the my_queue_key rather than the queue_name is what should be used.

```
queues:
    my_queue_key:
        provider: aws
        options:
            queue_name:                  my_actual_queue_name
```